# LaTeX 3: NewDocumentCommand with more than 9 arguments

Tags: expl3, xparse

I read an article on [this website](https://www.latex-project.org/publications/2010-JAW-TUB-tb99wright-xparse-NewDocumentCommand.pdf) introducing `\NewDocumentCommand`.
However, it does not answer such a question: does it breaks the limit that one `\newcommand` can have at most 9 arguments?

I found [almost the same question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/343677/latex3-more-than-9-arguments) where the author @egreg advices to use a comma-separated list of values, i.e.

```latex
\foo{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}
```

However, I do think that in this way we cannot own all the power of `\NewDocumentCommand`.
I wonder if this is the only way to solve the problem.

PS: I did not meet such a question in reality, and this is just a wonder.
I wrote a function with 8 arguments just now, and I am now scared at the situation where some day I want to write a function of more than 9 arguments.

Comment: No, the 9 argument limit is from TeX. You can't have _one macro_ with more than 9 arguments.  You can _emulate_ that in other ways though (for example here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2132/134574)

Comment: Will you remember the order of the arguments and their meaning one month after working out the definition?

Comment: @egreg Yes I believe I can, as I can make comments to it...
PS. when we write C++ or python or mathematica problems, we will always have a lot of arguments, but we can still remember their meaning as a result of comments...

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik So can we advice the team to change the style of accessing the n-th argument into something like... \arg{number here} or ##n to ###n
Thank you!

Comment: @CYQian C++ or python arguments are usded by name within a function body, tex ones by number and the syntax `#<single-digit>` is built in to the tex grammar you can't really make `#<digit><digit>` do anything

Comment: @CYQian expl3 is written in TeX it can not change the fundamental tex grammar,

Comment: @CYQian What if I want to use a nested definition (for which I need `##`)? Or what if I want to have an actual command called `\arg`?.  That can't be reasonably implemented, sorry (also 9 arguments is just awful to use: I prefer a command that remembers a bunch of defaults and I just give it what it _actually_ needs for each run)

Comment: @CYQian I normally forget the order of `atan2` (and it has just two arguments! ;-)). Jokes apart, I think the better solution would be to use a key-value package and have something like `\macro{x=1, y=0, }` etc with sane defaults. That mimics Python named argument and is a breeze to remember. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26771/a-big-list-of-every-keyval-package